# Пытаюсь вывести профиль пользователя и его посты на отдельную страницу через DetailView на Django

Tags: python, django

Вьюха

```py
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    
    model = User
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'blog/profile.html'
    paginate_by = POSTS_PAGE

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['profile'] = self.object.posts.author()
        context['posts'] = self.object.posts.filter(author__username=self.kwargs['username'])

        return context
```

Модель

```py
class Post(PublishedModel):

    title = models.CharField(
        'Заголовок',
        max_length=TITLE_MAX_LENGTH
        )
    text = models.TextField('Текст')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(
        'Дата и время публикации',
        help_text='Если установить'
        ' дату и время в будущем — можно'
        ' делать отложенные публикации.'
        )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Автор публикации',
        null=True
        )
    location = models.ForeignKey(
        Location,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Местоположение'
        )
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Категория'
        )
    image = models.ImageField(
        'Фото',
        upload_to='blog_images',
        blank=True
        )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'публикация'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Публикации'
        ordering = ('-pub_date',)
        default_related_name = 'posts'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title[:TITLE_MAX_STRING]
```

Форма

```py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ('author',)
        widgets = {
            'pub_date': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'},
                                            format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        }

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'


Урл

from django.urls import path

from blog import views


app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('profile/<slug:username>/',
         views.ProfileListView.as_view(),
         name='profile'),
    path('profile/<slug:username>/edit_profile/',
         views.ProfileUpdateView.as_view(),
         name='edit_profile'),
    path('posts/<int:pk>/',
         views.PostDetailView.as_view(),
         name='post_detail'),
    path('posts/create/',
         views.PostCreateView.as_view(),
         name='create_post'),
    path('posts/<int:pk>/edit/',
         views.PostUpdateView.as_view(),
         name='edit_post'),
    path('posts/<int:pk>/delete/',
         views.PostDeleteView.as_view(),
         name='delete_post'),
    path('category/<slug:category_slug>/',
         views.category_posts,
         name='category_posts'),
    path('posts/<int:pk>/comment/',
         views.add_comment,
         name='add_comment'),
    path('posts/<post_id>/edit_comment/<comment_id>/',
         views.edit_comment,
         name='edit_comment'),
    path('posts/<int:post_id>/delete_comment/<int:comment_id>',
         views.delete_comment,
         name='delete_comment'),
]
```

При переходе на станицу профиля выдает **Generic detail view ProfileDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.**
Ревьюер сказал что нужно именно через Detail делать и то что нужно "get_context_data в этом методе получи автора, и запиши его в контекст, получи из автора посты и запиши их в контекст"

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, ещё код `urls.py`.